# ObservableCollection в Backgroundworker

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть метод поиска файлов:

```
static public void FindLibrarys(String directoriesPath)
{
    ...
    //Ищет файлы. Каждый найденный файл передаёт в метод.
    ProgramsList.FormationProgramsList(file); 
}
```

Этот метод обрабатывает файл и помещает в свою ObservableCollection:

```
static public void FormationProgramsList(String file)
{
    ...
    // NewData возвращает новый экземпляр структуры.
    _fileList.Add( NewData(
                          fileName +
                          " | x" + bitCapacityProgram +
                          " | " +
                          myFileInfo.DirectoryName +
                          fileVersion +
                          productName,
                          _fileList.Count,
                          bitCapacityProgram == KompasCapacity
                        )
               );
}
```

Во ViewModel происходит привязка этой коллекции с коллекцией модели:

```
public ProjectViewModel()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _model = (ProjectModel)this.Resources["Model"];
    backgroundWorker = ((BackgroundWorker)this.FindResource("backgroundWorker"));

     _model.ProgramsList = ProgramsList.FileList;
    // Ну и с самим контроллом
    ResultName.ItemsSource = _model.ProgramsList;
}
```

Так вот мне надо было сделать этот поиск по кнопке, но чтобы интерфейс не подвисал. Я сделал через Application.DoEvent, но это Windows.Forms. По этому мне сказали попробовать другими средствами. Я решил попробовать через BackgroundWorker.

В VM, в обработчике кнопки вызываю:

```
backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
```

И написал такой код:

```
private void backgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (String path in _model.SearchPathsList)
    {
        if (_isContinueSearch)
        {
            LibraryFinder.FindLibrarys(path);
        }
        else
            break;
    }
}
```

Всё запускается, только при первом же найденном файле выдаёт исключение: System.NotSupportedException при добавлении элемента в коллекцию _fileList в методе FormationProgramsList.

Вопросы:

1. Можно ли с моей архитектурой проекта сделать, чтобы работало?
2. Не стоит ли изменить архитектуру?
3. Есть ли более удобные средства, которые можно было бы использовать вместо BackgroundWorker?

Изменения:

```
// Здесь я просто возвращаю кнопку в исходное состояние, т.к. при первом нажатии она меняет параметры и становится кнопкой остановки поиска.
private void backgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    // Возврат параметров поиска в исходное состояние.
    FindApp.Tag = true;
    FindApp.Content = "Найти приложения";
}
```

А ProgressChanged нету.

Comment: Покажите обработчики `RunWorkerCompleted` и `PropgessChanged`если он есть

Comment: вы хотите чтоб файлы добавлялись в список по мере их нахождения или все сразу?

Comment: Да мне как раз нужно, чтобы по одному добавлялись.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В таком случае нужно добавить обработчик события `ProgressChanged` и установить свойство `WorkerReportsProgress="True"` (там же в xaml, где добавляли обработчик 'DoWork`).

```
private void backgroundWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
     string file = (string)e.UserState;
     ProgramsList.FormationProgramsList(file); 
}

private void FindLibrarys(String directoriesPath)
{   
    //Ищет файлы. Каждый найденный файл передаёт в метод.
    backgroundWorker.ReportProgress(0, file);
}
```

К тому же сделать методы не статическими, иначе не будет доступа к `backgroundWorker` или передать ссылку на `backgroundWorker` в метод `FindLibrarys`.

Comment: Большое спасибо, буду пробовать. Сообщу о результатах.

Comment: Всё получилось, спасибо ещё раз.

Comment: @Сергей, рад помочь!)